# CheckBox return only false even it is checked(ticked)

Tags: java, android, checkbox

In my app, there are 2 check boxes to get the type of the user (Eg: Student or Teacher). I know I should use a radio button instead of a check box, but my question in tutorial asked to use a checkbox(So please ignore about radio button for now).

Even I check a checkbox, isChecked() method return false.

Here is the xml

```
        android:id="@+id/chkTeacher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="157dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="157dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="Teacher"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/regPassword" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkStudent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="157dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="157dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Student"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chkTeacher" />
```

Here is the coding

```
    EditText username, password;
    CheckBox teacher, student;
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    String type;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        username = findViewById(R.id.regUserName);
        password = findViewById(R.id.regPassword);
        teacher = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkTeacher);
        student = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkStudent);

        if (teacher.isChecked() == true){
            type = "teacher";
        }
        else{
            type = "student";
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this? Thank you for your valuable time!

Comment: `but my question in tutorial asked to use a checkbox` Yes. But only one. Not two. Try again. Start over. Only a teacher checkbox will do. All starts with reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Implement onCheckChangeListener
teacher = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkTeacher);
        student = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkStudent);

  teacher.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
if(isChecked){

    type = "teacher";
        }
        else{
            type = "student";
        }
     }
        });
```

student .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
if(isChecked){

```
type = "student";
    }
    else{
        type = "teacher";
    }
 }
    });
```

Comment: Now it is working only for "teacher". I think I should implement a setOnCheckedChangeListner for "student" too. Anyway thank you for your help!

Comment: yes you have to implement for student check box as well

Answer (score 1):

Well, as there is two different checkbox you have to work with both of those checkboxes and you have to trigger another checkbox's state as well. Hope this code snippet below will help you to achieve what you want.

```
    teacher = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkTeacher);
    student = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkStudent);

    if (teacher.isChecked() == true){
        student.setchecked(false);
        type = "teacher";
    }
    if (student.isChecked() == true) {
        teacher.setchecked(false);
        type = "student";
    }
```

Or you can use the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` like this:

```
result = findViewById(R.id.tv_res);
    teacher =  findViewById(R.id.cb_tec);
    student =  findViewById(R.id.cb_std);
    teacher.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (isChecked)
            {
                if (student.isChecked()) student.setChecked(false);
                type = "teacher";
            }
            result.setText(type);

        }
    });
    student.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (isChecked)
            {
                if (teacher.isChecked()) teacher.setChecked(false);
                type = "student";
            }
            result.setText(type);
        }
    });
```

Try the **second** solution which is working check:

[image: output]

Please have a look and Let me know if it works.

Comment: still the same. I checked "Teacher" but in the end "type" is null. BTW thank you for helping!

Comment: Oh! my bad. @ManujayaPremathilaka I have updated my answer. please check.

Comment: SetOnCheckChangeListner() solved my problem. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Very well then. @ManujayaPremathilaka Please mark my answer as the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For every chekbox just do this simple thing

```
myCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked){
            // do something
        }else {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
);
```

Comment: setOnCheckChangeListner worked. Thanks for helping!

Comment: if you found this is right answer please vote this answer. just click in the up arrow